# Script to convert lower case characters into upper case is working differently as service action

Tags: applescript

I am trying a simple script as a service action in automator which performs this function:

> Receives selected text in any application and replaces selected text
>   with the text containing capital letters

So I used this script:

```
on run {input, parameters}

set upperCaseString to ""
repeat with i in input
    if (ASCII number i) > 96 and (ASCII number i) < 123 then
        set upperCaseString to upperCaseString & (ASCII character ((ASCII number i) - 32))
    else
        set upperCaseString to upperCaseString & (ASCII character (ASCII number i))
    end if
end repeat

return upperCaseString
end run
```

But I found this problem:

> It was returning first letter of input as an upper case letter, eg.
>   input - lowercasetext, output - L, whereas the expected output was -
>   LOWERCASETEXT.

To check the problem I added this line of code in repeat loop:

```
display dialog i
```

and found that it is displaying complete text in place of single character at a time ,ie. in place of displaying l.. o.. w.. in lowercasetext it is displaying lowercasetext at once.

Can anyone suggest me why is it bugging me as service action while it is working fine in Apple Script Editor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will get the same result in the AppleScript Editor if the input variable is set to a list.  The input parameter of an Automator action is also a **list**, so your comparison isn't doing what you think.  Note that **text id**'s have obsoleted **ASCII character** and **ASCII number** commands - see the 10.5 AppleScript Release notes.

Answer (score 4):

This works for a lot of languages:

```
on toUpper(s)
tell AppleScript to return do shell script "shopt -u xpg_echo; export LANG='" & user locale of (system info) & ".UTF-8'; echo " & quoted form of s & " | tr [:lower:] [:upper:]"
end toUpper

on toLower(s)
tell AppleScript to return do shell script "shopt -u xpg_echo; export LANG='" & user locale of (system info) & ".UTF-8'; echo " & quoted form of s & " | tr [:upper:] [:lower:]"
end toLower
```

Answer (score 2):

When I run your script, I get the correct result. But one thing you may want to do is to explicitly coerce your result to text. The easiest way to do that would be at the end:

```
return upperCaseString as text
```

That may or may not do it for you, but you'll avoid a lot of frustration if you explicitly coerce data when there is a possibility of ambiguity.

Another (faster) way is to leverage the Unix **tr** (*translate*) command the via `do shell script`:

```
set upperCaseString to ¬
  (do shell script ("echo " & input & " | tr a-z A-Z;"))
```

That's enough for 'English' language, but you can also add diacritical translation, like so

```
set upperCaseString to ¬
  (do shell script ("echo " & input & " | tr a-zäáà A-ZÄÁÀ;"))
```

**tr** will translate *anything* to *anything*, so you can add any characters you may encounter and what you'd like them to translate to. A 'leet-speak' translator comes to mind.

Answer (score 0):

@Matt Strange:

You could also try:

```
set upperCaseString to ¬
  do shell script "echo " & input & " | tr [:lower:] [:upper:]"
```

If you run 'man tr' on 'OS X 10.10' you may see that the character classes [:lower:] and [:upper:] should be used instead of explicit character ranges like 'a-z' or 'A-Z', since these may not produce correct results as it is explained there, on the manual page.